# Selenium IDE: Bind mouseOver() on dynamically generated div

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

i have a div element which is created via JS on the fly.

```html
<div id='menu_item_0'>foo</div>
```

Now my Selenium IDE locator is able to access this element with various selectors, but whatever event like e.g. mouseOver or clickAt etc I use, they all seem to get ignored.

I could of course wirte some script an fire this, but i want to test exactly the mouseover by a mouse and not dispatch it by myself.

Anyone has an idea on this? The recorder does not record this too.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 1):

Can you show us the complete html and js ?

Here's a test code I've run with success. Does it match what you're trying to do ?

The HTML :

```
<html>
<body>
    <script>
    function insert(){
        var container = document.getElementById("container")
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.setAttribute('id','menu_item_0');
        newdiv.innerHTML = 'Added the element';
        newdiv.onmouseover = function(){
            newdiv.innerHTML = 'I feel tickled';
        }
        newdiv.onclick = function() {
            newdiv.innerHTML = 'I feel clicked';
        }
        container.appendChild(newdiv);
    }

    setTimeout(insert,2000);
    </script>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the selenium test (just save this in a .html file and open it from Selenium IDE) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="file:///G:/dev/proj/test-selenium-ide/" />
<title>test1</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">test1</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>index.html</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>menu_item_0</td>
    <td>2500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertElementPresent</td>
    <td>menu_item_0</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>mouseOver</td>
    <td>menu_item_0</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertText</td>
    <td>menu_item_0</td>
    <td>I feel tickled</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAt</td>
    <td>menu_item_0</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertText</td>
    <td>menu_item_0</td>
    <td>I feel clicked</td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I already tried something similar. But after hours and hours of looking through the code over and over I finally found the answer: In the JavaScript event handler library the events are overwritten and alwas return "false" in the end. This seems to prevent selenium and selenium IDE from accessing and dispatching the events.